# Nested sticky element with zero left does not sticky

Tags: html, css, sticky

Why my nested sticky element with `left: 0` does not stick while the nested element with `top: 0` sticks normally?

```css
.scroll {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 1px solid;
  overflow: auto;
}

.container {
  width: 600px;
  height: 1000px;
}

.sticky-left {
  position: sticky;
  left: 0;
}

.sticky-top {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="scroll">
  <div class="sticky-top">sticky-top</div>
  <div class="sticky-left">sticky-left</div>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="sticky-top">sticky-top-nested</div>
    <div class="sticky-left">sticky-left-nested</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's add some border and we will clearly see what is happening:

```css
.scroll {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 1px solid;
  overflow: auto;
}
.scroll > div {
  border:2px solid green;
}

.container {
  width: 600px;
  height: 1000px;
  border:2px solid red!important;
}
.container > div {
  border:2px solid green;
}

.sticky-left {
  position: sticky;
  left: 0;
}

.sticky-top {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="scroll">
  <div class="sticky-top">sticky-top</div>
  <div class="sticky-left">sticky-left</div>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="sticky-top">sticky-top-nested</div>
    <div class="sticky-left">sticky-left-nested</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

As you can see, the nested sticky elements are both having their width equal to parent width (since they are block element) so there is no room for the left-sticky to have any sticky behavior<sup>**1**</sup> since it has `width:100%` unlike the top one that can still stick because its height is less that the parent height.

For the non-nested elements I think it's clear.

---

Make the element `inline-block` or reduce the width and you will have a sticky behavior:

```css
.scroll {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 1px solid;
  overflow: auto;
}
.scroll > div {
  border:2px solid green;
}

.container {
  width: 600px;
  height: 1000px;
  border:2px solid red!important;
}
.container > div {
  border:2px solid green;
  width:150px;
}

.sticky-left {
  position: sticky;
  left: 0;
}

.sticky-top {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="scroll">
  <div class="sticky-top">sticky-top</div>
  <div class="sticky-left">sticky-left</div>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="sticky-top">sticky-top-nested</div>
    <div class="sticky-left">sticky-left-nested</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

> <sup>**1**</sup> A stickily positioned element is an element whose computed position value is sticky. **It's treated as relatively positioned until its containing block crosses a specified threshold** (such as setting top to value other than auto) within its flow root (or the container it scrolls within), at which point it is treated as "stuck" **until meeting the opposite edge of its containing block**.<sup>[ref](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position)</sup>

In your case you were always meeting the opposite edge.

Answer (score -3):

As per the [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position) on `position: sticky`, *the top, right, bottom, and left properties determine the final location of positioned elements*. My guess is that in order for it to be stickied from the top, it needs to also contain `top: 0`. The snippet I added seems to work.

```css
.scroll {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 1px solid;
  overflow: auto;
}

.container {
  width: 600px;
  height: 1000px;
}

.sticky-left {
  position: sticky;
  left: 0;
  top: 0; // Add this so it sticks to top
}

.sticky-top {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="scroll">
  <div class="sticky-top">sticky-top</div>
  <div class="sticky-left">sticky-left</div>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="sticky-top">sticky-top-nested</div>
    <div class="sticky-left">sticky-left-nested</div>
  </div>
</div>
```