# Why isn't position:sticky with left:0 working inside a scrollable container?

Tags: html, css, flexbox, sticky

I have this problem - I have a container that contains some rows and in each row there is a sticky left column and then multiple other columns. Now in the example below this works for a little while but as you scroll the parent container the position sticky no longer works and it gets pushed along as you scroll.

```css
.container {
  overflow-x: scroll;
}

.row {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  
}

.item {
  min-width: 173px;
}

.sticky {
  min-width: 250px;
  position: sticky;
  left: 0;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="item sticky">STICKY ROW 1</div>
    <div class="item">1</div>
    <div class="item">2</div>
    <div class="item">3</div>
    <div class="item">4</div>
    <div class="item">5</div>
    <div class="item">6</div>
    <div class="item">7</div>
    <div class="item">8</div>
    <div class="item">9</div>
    <div class="item">10</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="item sticky">STICKY ROW 2</div>
    <div class="item">1</div>
    <div class="item">2</div>
    <div class="item">3</div>
    <div class="item">4</div>
    <div class="item">5</div>
    <div class="item">6</div>
    <div class="item">7</div>
    <div class="item">8</div>
    <div class="item">9</div>
    <div class="item">10</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="item sticky">STICKY ROW 3</div>
    <div class="item">1</div>
    <div class="item">2</div>
    <div class="item">3</div>
    <div class="item">4</div>
    <div class="item">5</div>
    <div class="item">6</div>
    <div class="item">7</div>
    <div class="item">8</div>
    <div class="item">9</div>
    <div class="item">10</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Is there any way to solve this.. or is there another way to accomplish this??

My desired result is to be able to have the sticky div stuck on that left side a `0` and have the other columns scroll underneath..

Now I do know that if the `overflow-x: scroll` is on the actual `.row` element it works as expected.. but I may have 100+ rows so the scroll needs to be on the parent container

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Add border to better see the issue which is related to the use a block level element and the restriction of `width:100%` (not the one your are setting which is useless but the default behavior of block elements)

```css
.container {
  overflow-x: scroll;
}

.row {
  display: flex;
  border:1px solid;
}

.item {
  min-width: 173px;
}

.sticky {
  min-width: 250px;
  position: sticky;
  left: 0;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="item sticky">STICKY ROW 1</div>
    <div class="item">1</div>
    <div class="item">2</div>
    <div class="item">3</div>
    <div class="item">4</div>
    <div class="item">5</div>
    <div class="item">6</div>
    <div class="item">7</div>
    <div class="item">8</div>
    <div class="item">9</div>
    <div class="item">10</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="item sticky">STICKY ROW 2</div>
    <div class="item">1</div>
    <div class="item">2</div>
    <div class="item">3</div>
    <div class="item">4</div>
    <div class="item">5</div>
    <div class="item">6</div>
    <div class="item">7</div>
    <div class="item">8</div>
    <div class="item">9</div>
    <div class="item">10</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="item sticky">STICKY ROW 3</div>
    <div class="item">1</div>
    <div class="item">2</div>
    <div class="item">3</div>
    <div class="item">4</div>
    <div class="item">5</div>
    <div class="item">6</div>
    <div class="item">7</div>
    <div class="item">8</div>
    <div class="item">9</div>
    <div class="item">10</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Consider an inline level element using `inline-flex` to solve the issue. Add `min-width:100%` to make sure you cover at least `100%` of width if the content is small.

```css
.container {
  overflow-x: scroll;
}

.row {
  display: inline-flex;
  min-width: 100%;
  border:1px solid;
}

.item {
  min-width: 173px;
}

.sticky {
  min-width: 250px;
  position: sticky;
  left: 0;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="item sticky">STICKY ROW 1</div>
    <div class="item">1</div>
    <div class="item">2</div>
    <div class="item">3</div>
    <div class="item">4</div>
    <div class="item">5</div>
    <div class="item">6</div>
    <div class="item">7</div>
    <div class="item">8</div>
    <div class="item">9</div>
    <div class="item">10</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="item sticky">STICKY ROW 2</div>
    <div class="item">1</div>
    <div class="item">2</div>
    <div class="item">3</div>
    <div class="item">4</div>
    <div class="item">5</div>
    <div class="item">6</div>
    <div class="item">7</div>
    <div class="item">8</div>
    <div class="item">9</div>
    <div class="item">10</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="item sticky">STICKY ROW 3</div>
    <div class="item">1</div>
    <div class="item">2</div>
    <div class="item">3</div>
    <div class="item">4</div>
    <div class="item">5</div>
    <div class="item">6</div>
    <div class="item">7</div>
    <div class="item">8</div>
    <div class="item">9</div>
    <div class="item">10</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

Some related questions:

[Nested sticky element with zero left does not sticky](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53923923/8620333)

[Why is my element not sticking to the left when using position sticky in css?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57452412/8620333)

Comment: Perfect answer. Changed element to `inline-flex` and it now expanded to fit the width rather than limit itself to the 100% width.