# position:sticky ignoring right value in chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome, sticky

I have a very simple need: make and element sticky on the right side of the screen.

<del>All works fine in Firefox</del>, but in Chrome the `right: 0` property is ignored.
I said nevermind, I can achieve my goals by using `left: calc(100% - 80px);` but this is a lucky case, when I know the width of the sticky element.

However then I was baffled: while the workaround stated above works as expected (the elemtn sticks to the right), so does `left: 100%;`, so does `left: 2000%` for that matter, without triggering overflow (tested in Chrome and Firefox). I am clearly missing something. Maybe I don't understand left and right positioning of sticky elements, <del>although there are clearly differences between Firefox and Chrome.</del>

`left: calc(100% - var(--element-width))` totally makes sense, but can anyone explain: why is `right` ignored and why is `left: 100%` and `left: 2000%` for that matter also working (i.e. it positions the element where I would expect `right: 0` to position it, when it should clearly overflow.)

```css
.wrapper{
  width:100%;
  position:relative;
}
.container{
  height: 2000px;  
}
.floater{
  position:sticky;
  height:200px;
  width:80px;
  background:red;
  top:200px;
  right:0;  
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="floater">
        hei!
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54610362/8620333 .. right will not position the element. it doesn't work the same way as absolute and fixed

Comment: does this mean the Firefox behavior is actually wrong? `right: 0` works as (I) expected in FF.

Comment: Your code behave the same in both borwsers (at least for me) and it should behave the same in both unless you have a bug

Comment: You are right, I had some more convoluted structure which caused the right alignment to work in FF. Upon simplifying the structure, I experience the same thing in FF too. The rest of the question still stands. I'd like to understand right and left positioning of sticky elements.

Comment: read the link I shared, I am explaining for top/bottom and the same apply to right/left

Comment: Thanks, I saw a lot of top and bottom question but didn't realize it's the same issue with left and right.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are confusing between how `absolute` and `fixed` works compared to `sticky`.

> Sticky positioning can be thought of as a hybrid of relative and fixed positioning. A stickily positioned element is treated as relatively positioned until it crosses a specified threshold,  <sup>[ref](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position#sticky_positioning)</sup>

`right` and `left` will define the offset **only** when the element can stick on scroll. They will never position the element to the right or the left of the container.

Some examples:

```css
.box {
  border:2px solid;
  height:100px;
  margin:0 40px;
}
.box > div {
  position:sticky;
  height:100%;
  width:100px;
  background:red;
  right:20px;
  left:20px;
}

body {
  width:200vw;
}
```

```html
a left sticky behavior
<div class="box">
  <div></div>
</div>
I move the element to the right using margin and we have a right sticky behavior
<div class="box">
  <div style="margin-left:auto;"></div>
</div>
```

You can clearly see that the position of the element is not defined by left or right . right and left are only defining the distance the element should keep from the screen edges when we scroll.

Related questions for more details:

[Why bottom:0 doesn't work with position:sticky?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54609208/8620333)

[If you specify `bottom: 0` for position: sticky, why is it doing something different from the specs?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55965662/8620333)

[Why isn't position:sticky with left:0 working inside a scrollable container?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59619356/8620333)

Comment: what about left:200%; how does that work?

Comment: @brett Left:X --> the element should keep at least X distance from the left edge of the scrolling container WITHOUT overflowing its parent. X can be any value, 0, 200%, etc. You simply need to understand how sticky work and you will see that all the value works the same (I advise you to consider the link I shared for more details)